# Late 1970s hospital and helicopter building brick set

Tags: set-identification, sets, clone-brands, vintage, vehicle

I'm afraid I don't have a picture, but I am trying to identify a Christmas gift I fondly remember receiving as a child circa 1979.

It was a 3-foot box of building bricks and the front picture showed you could construct a hospital building and a helicopter.

The bricks inside were mostly white, with some of the smaller ones sporting a red cross and/or the word emergency in black on them. The majority of the bricks had six studs on top and six holes underneath - totally different from the LEGO, Betta Bilda etc blocks I have seen on this site and while searching online.

The bricks had slightly rounded edges rather than the hard, straight edges of bricks such as LEGO.

No figures or parts to make people were included, but there were little red door and window frames for the hospital. There was even a little round red boss to attach the helicopter's four rotor blades to.

As a child I simply called my blocks 'lego'... but I doubt very much that it was a LEGO set, having seen that LEGO pieces are different. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Most of us are Lego enthusiasts, so questions about clone brands (especially from 40 years ago!) are often hard for us to answer. Hopefully someone here has seen what you've described and can help out.

Comment: Were the studs in a row (1x6), or squared (2x3)?  Were they similar is size to Lego bricks?  Was the box 3 ft. high or wide?

Comment: In any case there doesn't seem to be [any LEGO brick with an "emergency" pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=7&q=emergency&catLike=W&sortBy=N&sortAsc=A&itemBrand=0&catType=P&catID=118&v=1)

Answer (score 1):

These blocks appear to match your description, would this be the type of brick you are talking about?  [image]

Comment: Your photo shows [American Bricks by Elgo / Halsam](http://www.balmoralsoftware.com/apb/aboutapb.htm),  they have 8 or 4 studs and  didn't have any printed parts

Comment: You are right, I was looking at tubes underneath being the same number as the studs on top.